# How to manage tokens in a spring boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth, jwt

I'm setting up new Spring Boot REST APIs for already established backend of my application. As a part of this, I have to provide authorization for protected resources on my server after user logs in. User session will be valid if time between last 2 requests is less than specified time. But I am having problem in selecting strategy for managing authorization token as token should expire after that time. Please help.

This is for a new Project on Spring Boot 2 and running on Jboss Application Server. I have tried generating new tokens for every request with expiry set to 30mins after that. But this approach has posed security problems as single user would have many valid tokens with him. Also, I have considered keeping my tokens in a key value store on server with token as key and timestamp as value.

Answer (score 0):

2 Solutions

- If you are using custom tokens than save it to the database and mark it as inactive whenever you want. (Not a good way compared to next option)
- Use JWT token with an expiry. (Do not create multiple tokens)